# Вывод HTML элементов при клике мыши

Tags: javascript

Пока плохо разбираюсь в JS,не подскажите как решить данную задачу ну или пояснить как эту задачу решить.

При клике на `<i>` с классом .itemAdd (см. прикрепленый код) в конец документа должен выводится этот же код но в содержание `<h4>` должен добавляться `<i class="close">x</i>`  то есть выводимый код должен выглядить так `<h4><a class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">10</span><i class="close">x</i></h4>`

Но при этом значение .item_price должно остаться таким каким и было в оригинале.

```html
<h4><a class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">10</span></h4>

<h4><a class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">20</span></h4>

<h4><a class="item_add" href="#"><i class="itemAdd">#</i></a> <span class=" item_price">30</span></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const my = document.querySelector('.my')
my.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName != 'H1') {
    return
  }
  document.body.append(e.target.cloneNode(true))
})
```

```html
<div class="my">
  <h1>A</h1>
</div>
```

Тут используется всплытие, event(е), методы для работы с документом. Надо обязательно учить js, я тут учил https://learn.javascript.ru/ . И да, в сторону jQuery не смотри (если только после js). jQuery это просто готовые решения, а надо разобраться что-как для понимания.

Comment: Во время оформления ответа... вверху есть темная кнопка `<>` для всавки кода)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME спасибо